# Extjs Combo return array and not only integer

Tags: javascript, extjs

I use a combobox with extjs.

When i submit my form the return of the combobox is an array. I need a string...

The return :

```
{"data":{"idAPourMutuelle":"","idOrganisme":["","1"],"idPersonne":"3","Mutuelle":""}}
```

And the combobox:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
anchor: '100%',
fieldLabel: 'Nom',
name: 'idOrganisme',
allowBlank: false,
editable: false,
displayField: 'Mutuelle',
hiddenName: 'idOrganisme',
store: 'Mutuelle',
valueField: 'idOrganisme'
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you want to access data within the returned object map, just access it. `retval["data"]["idOrganisme"][1]` or whatever you want.

Comment: not solved finaly, i need a integer, its the first time i have this bug

Comment: solved i have been an input hidden with the same name